# How to Downgrade PHPUnit 3.7.21 to 3.5.15

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I have a serious problem to downgrade PHPUnit to 3.7.21 to 3.5.15

I do this :

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPunit
```

// Uninstall OK
//i checked, PHP Unit is longer installed

then :

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15


C:\wamp\www\portailmg\dev\tests>pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15
Unknown remote channel: pear.symfony-project.com
Did not download optional dependencies: pear/XML_RPC2, use --alldeps to download
 automatically
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to do
wnload automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit requires package "channel://pear.symfony-project.com/YAML" (vers
ion >= 1.0.2)
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear/XML_RPC2"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use PHP extension "dbus"
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1
.0, version <= 1.1.99)
downloading DbUnit-1.2.3.tgz ...
Starting to download DbUnit-1.2.3.tgz (41,769 bytes)
............done: 41,769 bytes
downloading PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.0.tgz (42,240 bytes)
...done: 42,240 bytes
downloading PHPUnit-3.7.21.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.7.21.tgz (118,818 bytes)
...done: 118,818 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.7.21
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit-1.2.3
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.3.0
```

Then , when i check the current PHPUnit version by doing this : `phpunit -version`

I have my old version 3.7.21 installed !

Can anyone help me ?
thanks

PS : I tried this but not working for PHPUnit:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
 pear uninstall phpunit/DbUnit
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
 pear uninstall phpunit/File_Iterator
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_Timer
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
 pear uninstall phpunit/Text_Template
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
 pear uninstall pear.symfony-project.com/YAML
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_TokenStream




 pear install pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.2
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.1
 pear install phpunit/Text_Template-1.0.0
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.3
 pear install phpunit/PHP_Timer-1.0.0
 pear install phpunit/File_Iterator-1.2.3
 pear install phpunit/PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1
 pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.2
 pear install phpunit/DbUnit-1.0.0
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15
```

Comment: you can try `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15 --alldeps`

Comment: Not working unfortunately

Comment: you were very close !

Comment: The solution was to add --alldeps at the end of all pear install commands !

Comment: good that your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
 pear uninstall phpunit/DbUnit
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
 pear uninstall phpunit/File_Iterator
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_Timer
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject
 pear uninstall phpunit/Text_Template
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
 pear uninstall pear.symfony-project.com/YAML
 pear uninstall phpunit/PHP_TokenStream




 pear install pear.symfony-project.com/YAML-1.0.2 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium-1.0.1 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/Text_Template-1.0.0 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.0.3 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHP_Timer-1.0.0 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/File_Iterator-1.2.3 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHP_TokenStream-1.0.1 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.0.2 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/DbUnit-1.0.0 --alldeps
 pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.5.15 --alldeps
```

Answer (score 1):

install it via composer:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "pear.symfony-project.com"
        },
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "pear.phpunit.de"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/phpunit": "3.5.15",
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage": "1.0.*",
        "pear-pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator": "1.2.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked! It's a good way to get 3.5.15 working on legacy systems when on machine you got the phpunit 4.2..

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look as though phpunit 3.5.15 is currently available thru PEAR

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/924